# rubycode for signing a data-value and output of is not working

Tags: ruby

first of all, i want to be an artist not an programmer. i know programming is art too, but not my kind of art. so i'm sorry for wasting your time with my exercised, but i cant solve the last one, should be ruby code.

here is what to do:
i have an data variable data="mytest"
i have a key variable KEY="secr3t"

i should sign the data in data with the key in key and print it to the screen using the given function

```
def sign(data)
        OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new, KEY,data)
end
```

this function is given and the code should work with this part (mandatory). i have no idea what this is, and i dont want to know it in the future, looks to complicated to me.

this program should be in ruby. What i have puzzled until now with no success:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

class Test
    DATA = "mytest"
    KEY = "secr3t"
    def sign(data)
    OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new, KEY,DATA)
    end
end

# Create Objects
object = Test.new()
object.show
```

As a result of the programm should be a give an output in the following format

6d5bbfc847ec3638b5aed33b371044d6763cde45 
(40 digits when i count right with something in. )

The rest what i need to do (so ignore it, just for completion)
When the program is working, change data to your classname and key to "HAWHamburg" and send your answer to your teachers answermailbox.

by the way, did i mentioned that i will never be an programmer when i finished my school?

thanks for going through my question.

Paul

Comment: Your question is very unclear: what does this have to do with [tag:python]? What, *precisely* is it that you are trying to do? What, *precisely* is it you are having trouble with?

Comment: "no success" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases?

Comment: Also, your question is hard to read, there is a lot of unnecessary and completely unrelated stuff in there. In particular, paragraph #1 and the last few paragraphs are completely unrelated to your actual question. Please, read [ask] and also the particular guidance on homework questions on [meta]. Make sure to discuss your problems with your classmates, your TAs, your instructors, and your professors first. Make sure, you are asking the question in such a way that it is of value to the general programming community, and not just of value for you or your classmates.

Comment: yes sure, thats why you answered 4 ! Times.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. There is only 1 answer, and I didn't write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since **you don't like programming** I tried to make this answer a little more fun, with a little game for you. You need to complete the answer to have it working! The answer is based on what I believe you want to achieve, since your question is not extremely clear...

Here's the code! But **it is not complete**! You need to insert something in place of the question mark.

```
require 'openssl' # <- this suggestion is free for this time ;)

class Test
  def initialize()
    # All the instances will have the same key... soo secure!
    @secret = "secr3t"
  end

  # The sign method requires a chunk of
  # data to be digested
  def sign(????) # <- What is missing? 
    OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new, ???????, data) # <- What is missing.
  end
end


t = ????.???() # How do you create an instance??
puts t.sign("mytest") # prints the first digest 
puts t.sign("HAWHamburg") # prints the second digest
```

When you run it the answers are (almost, please notice that 6 chars have been hidden...):

```
31fd98b24d2d18f69d4d84f822b86343???18643
f5e01793af00b19f888dd66ec205d459???fd0fc
```

To get the  final result you have to finish the code by yourself. It is not difficult, you can do it!

Only if you really need a boost:

> Remember that each `?` correspond to 1 and only 1 char to insert `;)`

Comment: Hello Matteo, thanks for your answer. i will review it today as homework. Thanks for offering your time

Comment: worked as expected, really, really thank you. data, @secret, Test.new